# Android Apps Disappearing

Tags: android, google-play

I am having an issue of apps disappearing. I have two applications that have been uploaded to the same developer account. When both are downloaded (on the device at the same time), only one is visible. The other appears as if it is installed when you look under the apps portion under system settings. I cannot figure out why this is happening. Does this have something to do with how the apps were published?

Comment: in the one that is missing, did you remember to give the main activity the `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` in the `<intent-filter>` in the manifest?

Comment: Does both this app has same package name in maifest file?.  I hope both the app is signed with same keystore.

Comment: Some of my users have a similar problem, that I can't reproduce. I also have 2 Apps in same Devaccount. User downloads the apps and both are available. After a restart of the device one app is uninstalled.